# Where can I find Javascript color specification for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6

I am using Visual Studio Code to develop react-based user controls. I would like to know if there is a color specification available for JS/React in Visual Studio Code.

For example,

Functions are represented in White color.
Keywords are represented in purple color.

Also, is there a plugin that highlights functions, objects, anonymous functions, arrays, etc. in a way so that by looking at syntax it's easy to identify what exactly the line of code is representing?

[image]

Comment: choose a different theme or customize a theme

Comment: Is there a theme that has different colors for functions, objects, arrays, etc.?

Comment: you can customize every color for every TextMate Scope you want, or search the MarketPlace

Comment: I don't want to customize, I want the theme to tell me that this is an object, this is a function. So, looking for a explanatory theme.

Comment: how should it tell you it is a function

Comment: Like in Visual Studio it tells you by box icon, whether it's a variable or a function, then you can choose from the dropdown to go to that function.

Comment: hover your mouse over an identifier and you get a tooltip